# Jquery off() on element that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have an `iframe` that content is somehow loaded with ajax, not with content Location. This is WordPress customizer preview `iframe`. It's something like jquery mobile, the page in `iframe` flashes and new content is loaded. That said, I can't use load and unload events for this `iframe`, and I have to bind a click event listener to its contents.

So I came up with an idea to emulate load event. I will add javascript to the page that is loaded in an `iframe` and it executes `iframe` parent function when document is ready, the function then can bind the event listener to the new `iframe` contents.

But how can I unbind it, so I don't get any memory leaks? I tried adding an event listener on unload in the loaded page, but strangely, the unload event runs after the next page is already loaded, so the contents which have an event listener are already gone.

So basically there's no way I can `off()` the `iframe` contents before they disappear from the DOM. I have to `off()` them when they are gone, how can I do that?

**Edit**: 
I think I got it solved. Just store the contents in a variable. It seems like memory is not leaking anymore.

```
var iframeContents;

this.iframeLoadEmulation = function () {
   if (typeof iframeContents !=='undefined') {
      console.log('unbinding old content');
      iframeContents.off();
      iframeContents=null;
   }
   iframeContents=$('#customize-preview').find('iframe').contents();
   iframeContents.on('click', function(){ console.log('click'); });
}
```

Did I get that right? Is it a good code or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `beforeunload`?

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't execute at all.